# exposing public functions in Angular2 with Typesciprt through inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript, angular, extends

Let's say I have HealthBar component that extends a CommonComponent and I want to access a common event service in the baseComponent.

```
export class CommonComponent { 

constructor(private eventService:EventService){}

/*
broadcast (eventName, eventObj){
    let broadcastStr = this.name + " broadcast " + eventName;
    this.log(broadcastStr, eventObj)
    this.eventService.broadcast(eventName, eventObj );
}
*/

public broadcast = function(eventName, eventObj){
    this.eventService.broadcast(eventName, eventObj );
}
```

The healthBar can access the old "public broadcast = function" but not the new commented out broadcast() syntax. I thought they are the same thing, no? Why isn't broadcast() publicly available to the child component?

Comment: Can you show some code that reproduces your problem? Also, they're not the same thing—one is a method and the other is a property on the instance with a function assigned to it.

Comment: Did you call `super()` in your child component ?

Comment: you surely have a different problem. I just reproduced it and it works perfectly

Comment: cool thanks - I had the super syntax wrong and actually thought it was this.super not just super - super.broadcast() worked